# Encode to h265 with ffmpeg in batch

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have several Movies/Animes in Full HD and encoded in **h264** (current market standard), and I need to perform the Encode to **h265** of all these files (separated by folder and subfolders) to save space, which is the proper way to execute in batch (`.bat` file); below current code:

```
for %%f in (*.mkv, *.mp4) do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:a copy -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 lossless=1 -preset veryslow "Out\%%~na.mkv"
)
```

In order to have the best compression of the final file and better image quality (which is visually identical to the current **h264** file)

**Obs1:** I have both animations and movies and series with real people, can the "ffmpeg" configuration be different for each type?

**Obs2:** In most files have multiple audio and video tracks and multiple subtitles, it is necessary that all audio, video and subtitles remain in the final files.

Comment: for starters.. you are using `%%f` for your variable in the `for` loop and using `%%a` (and `%%~na`) in your statement.  This is probably not going to work out.

Comment: If you want lossless encoding you need to write `-x265-params lossless=1`... You will get huge files...

Comment: @PierU Will the x265 file size be larger than the original x264 file?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Quality will be lower, and the files won't shrink much at all. Or quality will be the same, but the files will be gigantic. Hard drives are cheap. You will waste an eternity reencoding a movie unless you have a beefy processor.

Comment: @Ricardo I don't know, it depends on how the x264 files had been encoded before. Anyway I tend to agree with the other comment, reencoding an already compressed video is often a not so good idea. If you have a Bluray source at 30Mb/s, you compress it at 4Mb/s with x264. If you compress the source at 2Mb/s with x265 you may get a similar quality, but if you recompress the x264 file with x265 it's another story.

Comment: @gargoylebident I wish I had the same quality as x264 but with x265 compression

Comment: @Ricardo then, like I said, you'd get much larger files than the x264 originals. In order to get the same quality at a _smaller_ filesize, you'd need to encode in 265 from disk/remux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Obs1:** see the `-tune` option. But x265 has less possible values than x264 for this option

> Choose a tune (optional). By default, this is disabled, and it is generally not required to set a tune option. x265 supports the following -tune options: psnr, ssim, grain, zerolatency, fastdecode. They are explained in the H.264 guide.

From https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265

**For Obs2:** only you can decide which tracks you want to keep in your files... To keep all the tracks you need to use the option `-map 0` in the `ffmpeg` command

Comment: For Obs2 I want all audio tracks, video tracks and all subtitles

Comment: @Ricardo OK, I have edited my answer